# How to resolve conflicts at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, exchange-server

Outlook has a neat conflict resolution system to solve the problem that sometimes your mails and the server mails are different. But sometimes it fails, and asks the user to solve it instead.
It would be troublesome to task a common user with that kind of job - Even more when a simple script or VSTO addin could do the job, without the need of user interaction.
But as far as I can tell by the [official Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868978.aspx), there's no way to really do it, either by VBA, .NET or VBScript, as the framework lacks a "Mark this object as winner" method or anything similar.
There's some kind of way to do it anyway, even without officially supported methods and calls?

It would be better if I could implement it using a VB.NET VSTO Outlook Add-in, but any other way would be acceptable.
For reference, the conflict would be resolved in the following way: The newer one always wins, and the change made by the local user running the Add-in always wins if the first one fails.
The conflicts are being generated by a Addin that categorizes the emails based on a Access database - it runs just fine, but on synchronization with the server, some users get sync issues - others do not.
As a lowly summer intern, I have no way to change Exchange configuration or anything like that.

One of my solutions was this piece:

```
Public Sub TryToResolveConflict()
    If MailItem.IsConflict Or MailItem.Conflicts.Count > 0 Then
        If MailItem.AutoResolvedWinner = False Then
            MailItem.Display()
            MailItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olSave)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It just opens the mailitem and closes it again, saving it, if any conflicts are detected and it's not the AutoResolvedWinner.
As any other poor constructed solution based on ignorance, it does nothing at all.

Comment: why not change settings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960288.aspx

Comment: @Claudius that article talks about creating new conflict resolution schemes on custom items. My problem is with a Outlook item, not a custom one. And alas I have no access to registry keys. It would require a special permission to every single computer, and a group policy is out of the question

Comment: Then VB.NET VSTO Outlook Add-in is out of question unless you are going to work on computer with access to registry, however you can create macro, but they won't run automatically so still need for a click

Comment: I would find what's causing a problem at your place and submit a ticket or work with IT manager to fix it. I don't think creating an add-in will solve anything.

Comment: I found the problem. Enterprise Vault kind of freaks out when you change properties of a mailitem with class "IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut"

Comment: Nice. Now work to fix it with IT. It's much easier to implement new preventive routine, than to implement new solution.